# Netbeans 7.3.1 Edit auto generated blocked code

Tags: java, database, netbeans

Help, Im busy with databases and I accidentally did the wrong thing and pressed the wrong button and this is so confusing I'm not even sure where I went wrong, I just know I need to remove an auto generated variable that netbeans added but it wont let me, and I cant run my program without removing it... How do I do this ?

[image]

Comment: pls provide more info

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E40938_01/doc.74/e40142/run_java_guis.htm#BCFECFII

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you dragged a table from the service database tab over to the Gui design screen. This can actually be quite useful way to quickly setup a table. Somehow later the classes must have gotten out of sync. 
To fix it:

1. Go back into the "GUI Design mode" for this class, using the "Design" button above the editor pane.
2. Find the Navigator window at the bottom left. (You can use Windows -> Navigator menu option if it is not visible).
3. Expand the Other Components node of the tree in the Navigator Window.
4. Select and delete the related items under the Other Components node of the tree. Look for the [Entity Manager] and [List] after the components name.